# How to check controller name

Tags: ember.js

I wanted to display the below html section in the index page only but it does not show up.

```
  {{#if name}}
  <header>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="intro-text">
              <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome To Our Joint!</div>
              <div class="intro-heading">It's Nice To Meet You</div>
              <a href="#services" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </header>
  {{/if}}
```

This is what i put in my index controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
name: function() {
    if (controller == this.get('IndexController')) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}.property()
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is an easier way to get the result that you want. Your controller code does not make any sense at all. The controller name will be **always** the same (your "if" never reaches the "else") because you are invoking the call inside of the controller. I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @givanse Ok so should i put the code from index controller into app.js file so that it is available to check across all, rather than just checking in the IndexController.

Comment: If you just want to show the above html, remove the controller code as well as the if condition. You do not need that at all. On what condition is the showing of your html content dependent on? I don't see any point of your controller code as well as the if condition on your handlebar template.

Comment: @Stuarty Basically I want to be able to show a piece of code if a controller is present, say like in rails I could do if controller_name == 'posts' So I just want a way to check the controller name either in template or in the controller and then pass the result down to the template.